# Angular 4+ Service referencing another service good practice

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, model-view-controller, components

I'm writing a software in Angular 4.x that, for every api request handled by the Service, needs to know the an information from another service (an Id).

My question, is about angular pattern and good practices. For my specific case, what would be the best approach:

1 - Using the Service A to call the Service B every time he needs to do the API Request with the ID information. Like this:

**Service A**

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {

  // ID
  public myId: string;

  [...]
}
```

**Service B**

```
@Injectable()
export class BService {

  constructor(
    private restangular: Restangular,
    private aservice: AService,
  ) { }

  public get(callback: (_: string[]) => void) {
    // Sends the request
    return this.restangular
      .all('myrequest')
      .customGET('', {
        myId: this.aservice.myid,
      })
    [...]
  }

  [...]
}
```

or

2 - Never call a Service from another Service and always use the component to first call the AService and then use the value on the BService (and thus having the same code replicated everytime an API call is made (or at least, one time for each component using that api call).

**Service A**

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {

  // ID
  public myId: string;

  [...]
}
```

**Service B**

```
@Injectable()
export class BService {

  constructor(
    private restangular: Restangular,
    private aservice: AService,
  ) { }

  public get(callback: (_: string[]) => void, myId: string) {
    // Sends the request
    return this.restangular
      .all('myrequest')
      .customGET('', {
        myId: myid,
      })
    [...]
  }

  [...]
}
```

**Component C**

```
export class CComponent implements OnInit {

  // List of api returned strings
  public apiList: string[] = [];

  constructor(
    private aservice: AService,
    private bservice: BService
  ) {
    this.bservice.get(result => {
      this.apiList = result;
    }, this.aservice.myId);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: 'Best practice' questions generally fall into off-topic category. Is there a chance that BService `get` will ever be called with any id except AService `myId`? Answer that and you will answer your own question.

Comment: Yes and no. For that Id it will always be AService myId, but it may need to call other id's from other services, not always.

Answer (score 1):

I have used inheritance to call another service. I made one Base service to set token or id information and if any service needs these tokens they can easily be extented by the base service. Here is an example

Base Service

```
    @Injectable()
export class BaseService {

  public myId: string;

  [...]
}
```

Other Service

```
@Injectable()
export class OtherService extends BaseService {

  constructor(
    private restangular: Restangular,

  ) { }

  public get(callback: (_: string[]) => void) {
    // Sends the request
    return this.restangular
      .all('myrequest')
      .customGET('', {
        myId: this.myid,
      })
    [...]
  }

  [...]
}
```

I generally use base service for setting authentication headers to authenticate apis.